# EXCEL VBA - formatting : merge, wrap text

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I've gotten help on this code from a very nice gentleman on SO. This part of the code basically writes a heading that spans over two columns, merge, and wrap-text. I generate this excel extract for headings of different lenghts. For some reports, if the headings are short the height is a regular cells, for others, its x3 in height, even though the length of the heading does not require that much height. Is there a way for me to specify that I want the ROW to always be...say 3 times the height of regular row HEIGHT. I don't want it to vary from report to report. Regardless of the length of the string, I want it to look the same. Is that something like that possible, if I'm using .merge, and .wraptext=true

```
Do While Not g_RS3.EOF
    With xlSheetInsurance.Cells(xlRow, xlCol)
        .Value = g_RS3("ShortLabel")
        With .Resize(1, 2)
            .WrapText = True
            .Merge
        End With
        .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2) = Array("# Clients", "# Students")
        .Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
        With .Offset(0, 1)
            .Resize(1, 2).Merge
            .Value = "TOTAL"
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 2) = Array("# Clients", "# Students")
            .Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 2).Formula = _
                "=SUMIFS(" & xlSheetInsurance.Range(.Parent.Cells(xlRow + 2, xlStartCol), .Parent.Cells(xlRow + 2, xlCol + 1)).Address(0, 1) & Chr(44) & _
                             xlSheetInsurance.Range(.Parent.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlStartCol), .Parent.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlCol + 1)).Address(1, 1) & Chr(44) & _
                             .Parent.Cells(xlRow + 1, xlCol).Address(1, 0) & Chr(41)
            .Offset(2, 0).Resize(1, 2).AutoFill .Offset(2, 0).Resize(7, 2) ' AutoFill formula for all Types
            .Offset(2, 0).Resize(7, 2).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
        With .Resize(2, 4)
            .Font.Bold = True
            .WrapText = True
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Borders.Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End With
    xlCol = xlCol + 2
    g_RS3.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: `.Row.Height = 45` *15 is default row height*

Comment: but where would i include it in this code. I'm looping through it and resizing it as I go. I'm not even sure why its giving me distinct row height

Comment: inside the `With .Resize(1, 2)` block where you specify `WrapText` and `Merge`

Comment: gives me an error - OBJECT REQUIRED

Comment: Sorry - wrong syntax it's `.RowHeight = 45`

Comment: great, post as answer. Thanks Scott!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you what you need:

```
    With .Resize(1, 2)
        .WrapText = True
        .Merge
        .RowHeight = 45
    End With
```